# How convert rdd row to a dataframe with json struct in pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-streaming, apache-spark-sql

I am sending the following json to the path "/ home / host / test" so that the program can capture it using spark streaming and be able to make queries about it.

```
{"id": "1", description: "test"}
{"id": "1", description: "test"}
```

But when I perform the query it looks like the following structure

```
root
   | --word: String (Nulleable = true)
```

and I get the following result:

```
+ ------------------- +
| word |
---------------------
| {"id": "1", "test"}
| {"id": "1", "test"}
```

---

I need the structure to look like this

```
root
   | --id: String (Nulleable = true)
   | --description string (Nulleable = true)
```

and I need to get a result like the following

```
 ----------------
| id | description
----------------
| "1" | "test" |
| "1" | "test" |
----------------
```

this is my pyspkark code

```
from __future__ import print_function
import os
import sys
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, explode
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext, Row
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext


if __name__ == "__main__":

sc = SparkContext(appName="PythonSqlNetworkWordCount")
ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 3)
sqlcontextoriginal = SQLContext(sc)

# Create a socket stream on target ip:port and count the
# words in input stream of \n delimited text (eg. generated by 'nc')
lines = ssc.textFileStream("/home/host/test")

# Convert RDDs of the words DStream to DataFrame and run SQL query
def process(time, rdd):
    print("========= %s =========" % str(time))

    try:
        # Get the singleton instance of SQLContext
        sqlContext = SQLContext(rdd.context)
        # Convert RDD[String] to RDD[Row] to DataFrame
        rowRdd = rdd.map(lambda w: Row(word=w))
        wordsDataFrame = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rowRdd).toJSON()

        json = sqlContext.read.json(wordsDataFrame)
        # Register as table
        json.createOrReplaceTempView("words")
        json.printSchema()

        wordCountsDataFrame = sqlContext.sql("select * from words ")
        wordCountsDataFrame.show()

    except:
        pass

lines.foreachRDD(process)
ssc.start()
ssc.awaitTermination()
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i found the solution.

I had to use sql.read.json passing it as parameter the rdd directly.

json = sqlContext.read.json(rdd)